# Calculating the adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having some trouble understanding the idea of cofactors and adjoints of matrices. From my understanding the adjoint of a matrix is the transpose of the matrix of cofactors?

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 
\\-1&3
\end{bmatrix}$

I need to find the adjoint when the following inner products are used on both the domain and target space:

a. the euclidean dot product

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 
\\-1&3
\end{bmatrix}$

so I thought the matrix of cofactors would be

$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 
\\-2&1
\end{bmatrix}$

(and I checked it with wolfram)

so the transpose of that would be 
$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -2 
\\1&1
\end{bmatrix}$

but my book is giving the answer $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 
\\2&3
\end{bmatrix}$

So my conclusion is that I did something wrong because I'm not considering the euclidean dot product? I see that the answer is $A^T$ but I don't understand how they got that answer.

b. the weighted inner product $<v,w>=2v_1w_1+3v_1w_1$ (is this supposed to be $<v,w>=2v_1w_1+3v_2w_2$? is this a typo? in my book?)

I am kind of confused even on how to apply this inner product, an idea I have is I have to separate A into a matrix v and w?

c. the inner product $<v,w>=v^TKw$ defined by the positive definite matrix

$K=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 
\\-1&4
\end{bmatrix}$

(I will try this after receiving some help above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing the adjoint of a matrix with its adjugate. The two are quite different beasts; the adjoint doesn't have anything to do with the cofactor or adjugate matrix.

The adjoint of a linear map $f : V \to W$, where $V,W$ are equipped with inner products, is the linear map $f^\vee : W \to V$ that satisfies
$$
\langle f(x), y \rangle_W = \langle x, f^\vee(y) \rangle_V
$$
for all $x \in V$, $y \in W$.

Now, you can calculate that if $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $W = \mathbb{R}^m$, both are equipped with the standard inner product and we write $A$ for the matrix of $f$ in the standard basis, then $A^\vee = {}^t\!A$. The way to do it is just to pick the standard basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $(w_1,\ldots,w_m)$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and calculate all the inner products
$$
\langle A v_j, w_k \rangle
$$
for $j = 1,\ldots,n$ and $k=1,\ldots,m$. That'll give you the matrix of $A^\vee$ (because $\langle A v_j, w_k \rangle = \langle v_j, A^\vee w_k \rangle$ by definition), which you'll find to be equal to ${}^t\!A$.

For the other inner products, just repeat that same process but use those different inner products. (There is a bit of a theoretical shortcut to calculate those out there; if you want to look for it then think about why all inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are isometric to the standard one, find how they are isomorphic in your case and reduce to the standard case. Or just calculate things brutally.)

Comment: oh..I just got the idea of the cofactor and adjoint from this youtube video, but I guess it's wrong. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaQV4nOqG6M

Comment: That video is complete nonsense.

Comment: The adjugate is sometimes referred to as [adjoint or "classical adjoint"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).  It really depends on the context.